# Pushing Typed text into data Layer GTM - No submit button

Tags: forms, google-tag-manager

I am trying to measure engagement (capture text input, send value into GTM data layer etc.) when a visitor clicks on dropdown and type into the text box (see screenshot).

The problem is, there is no submit button. Search and display is performed automatically. Wondering, is even possible to push entry text into GTM Data layer?

[Form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAOB0.jpg)

Here is the part of the script

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 481.5px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 151px;">
   <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></div>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 420.5px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 90px;">
      <li data-original-index="1" class="">
<a tabindex="0" class="indent-1 location-name" style="" data-tokens="null">
<span class="text">All Destinations</span><span class="fa fa-checkmark check-mark"></span>
</a>
</li>
      <li data-original-index="2" class=""><a tabindex="0" class="indent-1 location-name js-state-AL" style="" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">Alabama</span><span class="fa fa-checkmark check-mark"></span></a></li>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Were you able to achieve this or is it not possible with the setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via custom HTML tag. In the tag you write a custom listener for the keydown browser event. It's slightly complicated but described very well in the link below by simo ahava.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-autocomplete-search-google-tag-manager/

Hope that helps.